# More memory efficient option than numpy.where?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management

I have a large array (several million elements) and I need to slice out a small number of them (few hundred) based on several different criteria. I am currently using np.where, along the lines of:

```
for threshold in np.arange(0,1,.1):
    x=np.random.random(5000000)
    y=np.random.random(5000000)
    z=np.random.random(5000000)
    inds=np.where((x < threshold) & (y > threshold) & (z > threshold) & (z < threshold+0.1))

DoSomeJunk(a[inds], b[inds], c[inds])
```

and then later on using ipts to pull the correct points out of various arrays. I get MemoryError on that np.where line, however. I have seen on a couple other related posts that np.where may be a memory hog and copying the data.

Does having the multiple & in there mean that the data is copied multiple times? Is there a more efficient way to slice data in such a way that is less memory intensive that also preserves the list of indices I want so that I can use that same slice in multiple places later?

Note that this example I posted doesn't actually generate the error, but the structure is similar to what I have.

Comment: try using np.logical_and and applying the results to get only a small subset based on it :
 
-- your_array[  np.logical_and( iens < maxe, iangsdet_ofst > (11.25*azpt), iangsdet_ofst < (11.25*(azpt+1))  ]

Comment: What are the shapes of the different arrays there (`iens`, `azpt`, ...)? One option would be to batch the operation, taking slices of the big array and shifting the result of `np.where` accordingly. Also you could consider a Numba-accelerated loop instead of the vectorized operation, although you don't know the number of results in advance.

Comment: it's not clear from the name, but how you've used `where` isn't how it was meant to be used. for what you're doing `numpy.nonzero` might squeeze a little more performance out. (this doesn't really address your question about copies, but thought I'd add it anyway)

Comment: I tried to clean up the example a bit. This doesn't actually produce the memory error, but is similar to what I have in my actual code in terms of structure...

Comment: Try using `numexpr`

Comment: OK, so: it looks like the proximate cause of my problem was that one of my arrays was (a few million, 1) instead of just (a few million), so when I ran a squeeze on it, it worked OK. I don't fully understand why this is though...

Comment: `(x<.3)` generates a boolean array of the same shape as `x`.  `(x<.3)&(y<.3)` will produce a new boolean array whose shape depends on how `x` and `y` broadcast against each other.  So building the condition array could be quite memory intensive if `x`,`y` and/or `z` are large.   I dont think the `nonzero` itself uses much more memory - just the space needed to return its results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each of the conditions you are creating a temporary boolean array with the same size as `x`, `y`, and `z`. To optimize this you could iteratively create the mask:

```
for threshold in np.arange(0,1,.1):
    x=np.random.random(5000000)
    y=np.random.random(5000000)
    z=np.random.random(5000000)
    inds = x < threshold
    inds &= y > threshold
    inds &= z > threshold
    inds &= z < threshold+0.1

DoSomeJunk(a[inds], b[inds], c[inds])
```

For this example, this would reduce the memory usage from 160 MB to 40 MB.

Comment: OK thanks. So, to clarify then, could I also do inds = np.where(inds & (the next check)) to nest the wheres iteratively and that would also be less memory? Is there any specific reason for where vs the boolean array you have there?

Comment: The `np.where` calls in your example are superfluous since you can use fancy indexing with a boolean array to index an array. In other words `a[inds]` is completely equivalent to `a[np.where(inds)]`, but the latter requires the creation of a new array.

Comment: You can read more about boolean indexing here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays.